# get 'self', 'next' and 'previous' links (ember v2)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, json-api

I'm developing an Ember-js application where I'd like to link each 'article' to the next and previous article. I want to work according to the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/).

I've managed to load/show the article's (blog) author in a decent and to load and show a 'teaser' of the next (related) article. That works fine.

Now, the next piece should be fairly simple: **how can I load the 'links'** defined in my article? How can I add them to my model or show them in any other way in my Handlebars-template?

Let me give an exerpt from my JSON-repsonse (the payload):

```
{

  "data": {
    "type": "blogs",
    "id": "5",
    "links": {
      "previous": "blogs/4",
      "self": "blogs/5",
      "next": "blogs/6"
    },
    "attributes": {…}, // title, subtitle, bodytext, etc. 
    "relationships": {
        …
      },
```

The most important issue is how to get this 'self' link from the JSON reply. Can this data be used straight from the 'model'?

My model looks as follows:

```
//models/blog.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  nid        : DS.attr('string'),
  title      : DS.attr('string'),
  subtitle   : DS.attr('string'),
  intro      : DS.attr('string'),
  …
  author     : DS.belongsTo('person'),
  next       : DS.attr('next'),
  previous   : DS.belongsTo('person')
});
```

---

UPDATE
As @bungee points out, there's a an error (against the JSONAPI specs) in the payload. The 'links' array should be sibling to 'data', not descendent. However, in Ember 2.8, that still won't make Ember 'eat' it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a data adapter? If so, have you created a model that corresponds to the data structure you displayed. To me it looks like that's not a standard ember rest data structure, but it depends on the adapter you're using. Also it looks like you could consider setting previous, self and next as direct parameters to data..?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've added the file containing the model to the question.

I use the standard JSONAPIAdapter.

You say it doesn't look like the standard ember rest data structure. What part doesn't?

Comment: the links parameter doesn't look like standard ember rest format. I'd expect links to be, for instance a one to many relationship and simply an array of id's like so: ```links: [ 'id123987', 'id12308', ... ]```. Or like I suggested just have the links as direct attributes to the parent: { previousLink: "blogs/4", selfLink: "blogs/5", nextLink: "blogs/6" }. But can be that you know something I don't.

Comment: You're right in that I was ALSO wrong in adding the 'previous', 'self' and 'next' links as direct parameters to data. Their parent, 'links' should be a sibling of data. Then, still, it will not work because Ember doesn't know how to digest it.

Comment: looking at the link https://emberigniter.com/pagination-in-ember-with-json-api-backend/ posted by @Ideogram, the example is taking the links parameters from the payload and putting them under meta.pagination. So as he says: it seems pagination links aren't currently supported out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Based on help from the Ember community (Slackware), I found out that at the moment this is not possible:

https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination/issues/144

https://emberigniter.com/pagination-in-ember-with-json-api-backend/

To answer Bungee's comment:the JSON-API (http://jsonapi.org/) specifies that these 'previous','self' and 'next' links *should* be under the root of the payload but we *can‘t*

We can indeed solve the problem by moving them under 'data' → 'attributes' in the payload if can live with idea of not adhering to the JSON-API specs.

By the way: quote from the JSON-API's:

```
Pagination links MUST appear in the links object that corresponds to a collection. To paginate the primary data, supply pagination links in the top-level links object.

[…]

The following keys MUST be used for pagination links:

    first: the first page of data
    last: the last page of data
    prev: the previous page of data
    next: the next page of data
```